# Is there any document for creating and testing WSO2 REST API

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have created REST API using WSO2 API manager and published. But when I try out it not working. I did subscribe to app and created token and using https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrej9.png that token i did tried, but no fruitful result.
I have followed official document. I am working with WSO2-am 3.0.0 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the QSG doc.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/getting-started/quick-start-guide/

Note from step 3.3:

> If this is the first time you are using the API test console from your
>   browser, open a new tab and navigate to the https://localhost:8243/
>   URL.
>
> This will prompt your browser to accept the certificate used by the
>   API Gateway. This is required because by default the API Gateway uses
>   a self-signed certificate that is not trusted by web browsers.

Comment: Thanks. I can get response this way but from mocky, but i want to create my own rest api for crud operation with MySQL database.

Comment: APIM is there to apply QoS policies on top of your existing APIs. If you want to build a REST API for the data in a table you can use Data Services in WSO2 EI. See https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Working+with+Data+Services+.